# WooCommerce Product MySQL query is taking too long with ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 25000+ products available in WooCommerce.

I am querying my products with the CUSTOM MYSQL query because I want minimal data to fetch instead of getting the whole products in an object.

The Query is working fine and it is as below:

```
SELECT 
        p.ID, 
        m1.meta_value as 'cut', 
        m2.meta_value as 'polish', 
        m3.meta_value as 'symmetry', 
        m4.meta_value as 'fluor_intensity', 
        m5.meta_value as 'short_name', 
        m6.meta_value as 'total_sales_price',
        m7.meta_value as 'available',
        m8.meta_value as 'lab',
        m9.meta_value as 'shape', 
        m10.meta_value as 'size', 
        m11.meta_value as 'color', 
        m12.meta_value as 'clarity', 
        m13.meta_value as 'depth_percent', 
        m14.meta_value as 'table_percent',
        m15.meta_value as 'meas_length',
        m16.meta_value as 'meas_width',
        m17.meta_value as 'meas_depth',
        m18.meta_value as 'price_per_caret',
        m19.meta_value as 'fancy_color',
        m20.meta_value as 'fancy_intensity',
        m21.meta_value as 'image',
        m22.meta_value as 'meas_ratio',
        m23.meta_value as 'treatment',
        m24.meta_value as 'culet_size'
        FROM
         wp_u8gwgg_posts p 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m1 ON p.id = m1.post_id AND m1.meta_key = '_diamond_cut' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m2 ON p.id = m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key = '_diamond_polish' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m3 ON p.id = m3.post_id AND m3.meta_key = '_diamond_symmetry' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m4 ON p.id = m4.post_id AND m4.meta_key = '_diamond_fluor_intensity' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m5 ON p.id = m5.post_id AND m5.meta_key = '_diamond_shortname' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m6 ON p.id = m6.post_id AND m6.meta_key = '_price' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m7 ON p.id = m7.post_id AND m7.meta_key = '_diamond_available' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m8 ON p.id = m8.post_id AND m8.meta_key = '_diamond_lab' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m9 ON p.id = m9.post_id AND m9.meta_key = '_diamond_shape' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m10 ON p.id = m10.post_id AND m10.meta_key = '_diamond_size' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m11 ON p.id = m11.post_id AND m11.meta_key = '_diamond_color' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m12 ON p.id = m12.post_id AND m12.meta_key = '_diamond_clarity' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m13 ON p.id = m13.post_id AND m13.meta_key = '_diamond_depth_percent' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m14 ON p.id = m14.post_id AND m14.meta_key = '_diamond_table_percent' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m15 ON p.id = m15.post_id AND m15.meta_key = '_diamond_meas_length' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m16 ON p.id = m16.post_id AND m16.meta_key = '_diamond_meas_width' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m17 ON p.id = m17.post_id AND m17.meta_key = '_diamond_meas_depth' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m18 ON p.id = m18.post_id AND m18.meta_key = '_diamond_price_per_carat' 
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m19 ON p.id = m19.post_id AND m19.meta_key = '_diamond_fancy_color'
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m20 ON p.id = m20.post_id AND m20.meta_key = '_diamond_fancy_intensity'
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m21 ON p.id = m21.post_id AND m21.meta_key = '_knawatfibu_url'
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m22 ON p.id = m22.post_id AND m22.meta_key = '_diamond_meas_ratio'
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m23 ON p.id = m23.post_id AND m23.meta_key = '_diamond_treatment'
            LEFT JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m24 ON p.id = m24.post_id AND m24.meta_key = '_diamond_culet_size'
            WHERE p.post_type = "product" 
        ORDER BY total_sales_price+0 ASC
        LIMIT 0, 12
```

The real struggle occurs when I am adding, `ORDER BY total_sales_price+0 ASC` in my query.

So, when I am not adding the `ORDER BY` clause, the query is giving me results in around **0.02s**
And the same query with `ORDER BY` is giving me results in around **9.4s**

Questions:

1. How can I just decrease the fetching records time with `ORDER BY` clause?
2. Is there any way by which this query can perform better for end-users?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: show output of `explain select rest-of-your-query`, with and without the order by, and output of `show create table wp_u8gwgg_posts` and `show create table wp_u8gwgg_postmeta`

Comment: do you have products with no value for the _price meta key?

Comment: The problem here is when the query is going to sort the data ( When using ORDER BY ) from 25000 records, it is taking too long along with Left joins. Otherwise, the Query with LEFT JOINs is also giving me perfect timing.

Comment: All products have _price meta key. There is no product with an empty meta_key

Comment: So whether it's two LEFT JOINs or 24 makes no (or only negligible) difference to query performance?

Comment: No. It is not giving results at the same time for 2 left joins and 24 left joins. When left joins are increasing, the time to fetch the records will also increase. But it is not affecting drastically. it is just a matter of `0.001s` of difference increasing the left joins, what bothers me here is, it is taking time when the data is going to `ORDER`.

Comment: @MalavVasita - They way the schema is designed conspires to make more JOINs and ORDER BY + LIMIT suffer when the number of rows _or_ JOINs increases.  See my Answer for partial mitigation of both causes of slowing down.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter wp_u8gwgg_posts and price first by using a sub-query and filtering the number of sorted rows. Then only left join the rest. That should limit the number of rows you need to join.

```
select
   p.id,
   m1.meta_value as 'cut',
   m2.meta_value as 'polish',
   m3.meta_value as 'symmetry',
   m4.meta_value as 'fluor_intensity',
   m5.meta_value as 'short_name',
   p.total_sales_price,
   m7.meta_value as 'available',
   m8.meta_value as 'lab',
   m9.meta_value as 'shape',
   m10.meta_value as 'size',
   m11.meta_value as 'color',
   m12.meta_value as 'clarity',
   m13.meta_value as 'depth_percent',
   m14.meta_value as 'table_percent',
   m15.meta_value as 'meas_length',
   m16.meta_value as 'meas_width',
   m17.meta_value as 'meas_depth',
   m18.meta_value as 'price_per_caret',
   m19.meta_value as 'fancy_color',
   m20.meta_value as 'fancy_intensity',
   m21.meta_value as 'image',
   m22.meta_value as 'meas_ratio',
   m23.meta_value as 'treatment',
   m24.meta_value as 'culet_size' 
from
   (
      select
         aa.id,
         m6.meta_value as 'total_sales_price' 
      from
         wp_u8gwgg_posts aa 
         left join
            wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m6 
            ON aa.id = m6.post_id 
            and m6.meta_key = '_price' 
      where
         aa.post_type = "product" 
      order by
         m6.meta_value + 0 asc limit 0,
         12 
   )
   as p 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m1 
      on p.id = m1.post_id 
      and m1.meta_key = '_diamond_cut' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m2 
      on p.id = m2.post_id 
      and m2.meta_key = '_diamond_polish' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m3 
      on p.id = m3.post_id 
      and m3.meta_key = '_diamond_symmetry' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m4 
      on p.id = m4.post_id 
      and m4.meta_key = '_diamond_fluor_intensity' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m5 
      on p.id = m5.post_id 
      and m5.meta_key = '_diamond_shortname' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m7 
      on p.id = m7.post_id 
      and m7.meta_key = '_diamond_available' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m8 
      on p.id = m8.post_id 
      and m8.meta_key = '_diamond_lab' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m9 
      on p.id = m9.post_id 
      and m9.meta_key = '_diamond_shape' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m10 
      on p.id = m10.post_id 
      and m10.meta_key = '_diamond_size' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m11 
      on p.id = m11.post_id 
      and m11.meta_key = '_diamond_color' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m12 
      on p.id = m12.post_id 
      and m12.meta_key = '_diamond_clarity' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m13 
      on p.id = m13.post_id 
      and m13.meta_key = '_diamond_depth_percent' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m14 
      on p.id = m14.post_id 
      and m14.meta_key = '_diamond_table_percent' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m15 
      on p.id = m15.post_id 
      and m15.meta_key = '_diamond_meas_length' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m16 
      on p.id = m16.post_id 
      and m16.meta_key = '_diamond_meas_width' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m17 
      on p.id = m17.post_id 
      and m17.meta_key = '_diamond_meas_depth' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m18 
      on p.id = m18.post_id 
      and m18.meta_key = '_diamond_price_per_carat' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m19 
      on p.id = m19.post_id 
      and m19.meta_key = '_diamond_fancy_color' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m20 
      on p.id = m20.post_id 
      and m20.meta_key = '_diamond_fancy_intensity' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m21 
      on p.id = m21.post_id 
      and m21.meta_key = '_knawatfibu_url' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m22 
      on p.id = m22.post_id 
      and m22.meta_key = '_diamond_meas_ratio' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m23 
      on p.id = m23.post_id 
      and m23.meta_key = '_diamond_treatment' 
   left join
      wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m24 
      on p.id = m24.post_id 
      and m24.meta_key = '_diamond_culet_size' 
order by
   p.total_sales_price + 0 asc
```

Comment: Hey @Vlam, Thank you for the answer. It really performed well in my case. I just have a doubt that. this is just a case of one column `ORDER` that is `total_sales_price`. What if I have to add the multiple `ORDER BY` clauses such as `shape`, `size`, `color`?

How can I implement that in a sub query?

Comment: EDIT: To clarify the above comment, I know how to implement the things in sub-query, but adding more than one `ORDER BY` means we have to add more than one left joins. as well. But the situation will be the same as right now. So I wanted to ask may we implement any betterment over there?

Comment: If you keep adding to the `order by` in the sub-query, then it will get bogged down again. I don't see any way to optimize that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have implemented the **Lookup table** concept from WooCommerce.

You can check the doc here: https://developer.woocommerce.com/2019/04/01/performance-improvements-in-3-6/

My search timing before was `15-20 seconds` before applying the lookup table.
And now it down to `1.5-3 seconds`

I just needed to change the query to:

```
SELECT 
    p.ID, 
    p.cut as 'cut', 
    p.polish as 'polish', 
    p.symmetry as 'symmetry', 
    p.fluor_intensity as 'fluor_intensity', 
    p.short_name as 'short_name', 
    p.total_sales_price as 'total_sales_price',
    p.available as 'available',
    p.labshape as 'labshape',
FROM
    wp_u8gwgg_app_data p
ORDER BY total_sales_price+0 ASC
LIMIT 0, 12
```

Left Joins are `GONE` now and all data I can Look it under 1 table.

If anyone is looking for the same, can implement the Lookup table for speed optimization.

Comment: Make the `total_sales_price` a numeric column; the `+0` is hurting performance.  Then add `INDEX(total_sales_price)`  (I think you are finding out why WP's schema design is problematic.)

Answer (score 0):

Two speedups:

- A solution to some WP (or Woo) performance issues:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta -- This will speed up much of WP and WooCommerce, especially for a 24-way `JOIN` like you have.
- Find the rows first, *then* do all those joins.

Here's what I mean by the first suggestion:

First, let's find the 12 items you want:

```
SELECT  p2.ID, 
        m6.meta_value
    FROM wp_u8gwgg_posts p2 
    JOIN wp_u8gwgg_postmeta m6 ON p2.id = m6.post_id
                              AND m6.meta_key = '_price' 
    ORDER BY total_sales_price+0 ASC
    LIMIT 0, 12
```

Note that I used `JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`.  Don't use `LEFT` unless the 'right' table is really optional.  Having the improved index as mentioned in the link above will help even this query.

Next, use that as a subquery to do the rest of the work:

```
SELECT  x.ID, 
        m1.meta_value as 'cut', 
        m2.meta_value as 'polish', 
        m3.meta_value as 'symmetry', 
        m4.meta_value as 'fluor_intensity', 
        x.meta_value as 'short_name',          -- note
        m6.meta_value as 'total_sales_price',
        m7.meta_value as 'available',
        ...
    FROM ( ... the query above ...)
    JOIN wp_u8gwgg_posts p2 USING(ID)    -- again (to get other columns)
    LEFT JOIN ...
    LEFT JOIN ...   -- the rest of the JOINs  (skip m6)
    ORDER BY total_sales_price+0 ASC   -- yes, repeated
    -- no need for LIMIT, unless the JOINs lead to dups
```

It would be *much* better if `price` were a *numeric* column in the `posts` table, but that violates the generality of WP and Woo, wherein the value(s) you want to filter on or order by are not easily accessible.

Comment: I think you are right, total_sales_price should be numeric. That change is accepted. But the query that I needed now with the Lookup table is running very well. And it gives me results in 0.0015 seconds. To form the data and show it to the front-end, it nearly takes 1.5-2 seconds.

Comment: `0.0015 seconds` smells like a Query cache result.  Time it using `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`